# How can I have C functions coloured based on whether they are defined?

Tags: colors, c, gtags

Colleague of mine showed me a cool feature of gnome-builder which does colour symbols based on whether they are defined or not and I was wondering whether it is possible in Emacs as well.  And by that I mean whether there is already an existing solution so that I don't have to write the whole colouring backend or something like that.  I'm color-theme noob, I just have one that suits me and use it.  So, if there's an easy way how to add that feature by hooks, that's still fine.  I'm currently using `gtags` backend for `helm` if that helps.